# how to stop a script to start xampp by default in a startup

Tags: nvidia, gedit, lamp

i was wondering about how to start xampp in my ubuntu 13.04 just with a script, i end up with a script that will start xampp after i start my machine automatically. what i did is : `sudo gedit /etc/init.d/lampp`
 a lampp file open with gedit. then

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

paste it in lampp

to make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/lampp
```

run following command to install init scripts to all runlevel

```
sudo update-rc.d lampp defaults
```

i got success after i rebooted and xampp starts automatically
but when rebooting a script is running in a black background which i think is initialising the xampp and starting it.

now i want to remove it as its forcing xampp to start with bootloader.so for that i opened lamp file again in gedit and removed the lines `#!/bin/bash
/opt/lampp/lampp start` . my xampp is not starting after a reboot but the script is initialising with bootloader before login screen come. is there a way to rever that update command or stop it by default?

and also after that i am facing a serious screen resolution problem where my screen comes to type laptop and 640 reso before i was running in 1024*768 with 75hz . i have configured it with `monitors.xml` file located in `home/config/monitors.xml` i have updated my nvidia drivers with sudo apt-get install nvidia-current.and i could not configure nvidia drivers by typing `gksu nvidia-xconfig` its asking for admin password when i enter  it exiting. the admin password i guess i am giving wrong putting my username password

thnks for the help in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it with the following command:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f lampp remove
```

Comment: Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/lampp ...
 i think the script is removed. thnkx and i fixed my resolution by reverting back to the previous using x.orgxserver-nouveau display driver. thnkx for the help man.